# Facebook Graph API how to link saved audience (or reuse targeting) to adsets

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I want to reuse targeting across my adsets in Facebook. After checking their documentation, seems like using saved audiences is the answer. Upon checking the Targeting Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs/v2.8 I dont find an option to reuse Saved Audiences (or target data) while creating new audiences. There are options to link Custom Audiences, but not other Targeting fields.

Anyone who has encountered a similar issue or any help would be appreciated in reusing FB targeting via the API.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Graph Api to get Ids of saved audiences (act_AD_ACCOUNT_ID/saved_audiences)
And then use Id to get targeting:
saved_audience_id?fields=targeting